# webpack require non-js content in jest unit-tests

Tags: webpack, babeljs, jestjs, babel-jest

Recently I've converted one of my projects to webpack & babel. It is made out of knockout components.

I'm running into a problem while running the unit-tests. If I have a file in the  **tests** folder like

```
import component from '../custom-options';

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(3).toBe(3);
});
```

The problem is that the component is a module which has a require of the sort

```
var htmlString = require('./custom-options.html');
```

When I try to run the website itself it runs fine, as the raw loader is configured for this require. However, when I run jest the test outputs:

```
 custom-options.html:1
 ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){?<div id="custom-options-containe" class="mod--custom-options">
                                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

  at transformAndBuildScript (node_modules\jest-cli\node_modules\jest-runtime\build\transform.js:284:10)
  at custom-options.js:13:38
  at Object.<anonymous> (custom-options.js:93:3)
```

Any idea why this is happening? I thought jest was at fault but I've tried subbing it out with Ava and the result is the same. I'm beginning to think it's a babel problem.

I'm running jest with the babel-jest preprocessor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a global mock for all none JS files in you jest settings in the `package.json` like this:

```
"jest": {
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^.+\\.html$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/htmlMock.js"
  }
}
```

then create the file `htmlMock.js` in the `__mocks__` folder in your project root with the following content:

```
module.exports = 'test-file-stub';
```

For more info have a look [here](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-webpack.html#content)

If you want do have a special mock for every test case you can also mock the file in your test like this:

```
jest.mock('path/from/test/to/custom-options.html', ()=> 'test-file-stub');
```

Notice that the path is relative to the test file not to the file you want to test.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`jest-raw-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-raw-loader) to mimic the action of [webpack's `raw-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/).
You need to set it up as a [`transform`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#transform-objectstring-pathtotransformer--pathtotransformer-object), and be sure to include the default `babel-jest` transform entry as well.

```
"jest": {
  "transform": {
    "\\.js$": "babel-jest",
    "\\.(html|xml|txt)$": "jest-raw-loader"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes to this. Adding the default transform for js files is primordial. Please note that the configuration above is part of the jest.config.js file.