# Jest Testing with require modules: ejs-loader

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ejs, jestjs

I am playing with the idea of having large static html bundles just loaded into a react component vice typing them all out in `jsx`. I am currently just experimenting with [ejs-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs-loader) and [html-react-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser) to evaluate the feasibility of this. Everything actually renders fine but I cannot get any tests to work with `jest` for this.

I receive: `Cannot find module ejs-loader!./AboutPage.view.ejs` from `AboutPage.js` errors and I am unsure of what to do.

I am currently just working off of [react-slingshot](https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot) as my base for experimenting with this.

The repo for the project is [here](https://github.com/AndrewPHunter/react-ignition)

The component itself is simple:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Parser from 'html-react-parser';
import '../styles/about-page.css';

const view = require('ejs-loader!./AboutPage.view.ejs')();

// Since this component is simple and static, there's no parent container for it.
const AboutPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {Parser(view)}
    </div>
  );
};

export default AboutPage;
```

And the test is:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import AboutPage from './AboutPage';

describe('<AboutPage />', () => {
  
  it('should have a header called \'About\'', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<AboutPage />);
    const actual = component.find('h2').text();
    const expected = 'About';

    expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
  });
  
});
```

I have read through [the docs](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/webpack.html) and similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302246/webpack-require-non-js-content-in-jest-unit-tests). I attempted to use a custom transformer, but I may be misunderstanding something as it doesn't appear to be even called.

Package.json

```js
"jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
      "^.+\\.(gif|ttf|eot|svg|woff|woff2|ico)$": "<rootDir>/tools/fileMock.js"
    },
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
      "\\.(ejs|ejx)$": "<rootDir>/tools/ejx-loader/jest.transformer.js"
    }
  },
```

and the transformer itself:

```js
module.exports = {
  process(src, filename, config, options){
    console.log('????');
    return 'module.exports = ' +  require(`ejs-loader!./${filename}`);
    //return require(`ejs-loader!./${filename}`);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing module name mapper to -

`{
  "\\.(css|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
  "^.+\\.(gif|ttf|eot|svg|woff|woff2|ico)$": "<rootDir>/tools/fileMock.js"
  "ejs-loader!(.*)": "$1",
}`

This should at least invoke your custom transformer.

Also the custom transformer should be -

```
const _ = require('lodash');
module.exports = {
  process(src, filename, config, options){
    console.log('????');
    return 'module.exports = ' +  _.template(src);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you've specified `.ejs` as a [`moduleFileExtension`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#modulefileextensions-array-string).

```
"jest": {
  ...
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "jsx", "ejs", "ejx"],
  ...
}
```

Also, `ejs-loader` will export the function using cjs syntax for you, so you can do the following in your transformer:

```
const loader = require('ejs-loader');

module.exports = {process: loader};
```

Answer (score 0):

Work for me:

```
"jest": {
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    '\\.(ejs|ejx)$': '<rootDir>/jest-ejs.transformer.js'
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'json', 'jsx', 'ejs']
},
```

In `jest-ejs.transformer.js`

```
const loader = require('ejs-loader');
module.exports = {process: loader};
```